# Send mail service start error

Tags: centos, centos7, sendmail

I installed sendmail on CentOS based on some tutorial. When I start sendmail, it showing sendmail failed error.

Here the following command result:

```
systemctl status sendmail
sendmail.service - Sendmail Mail Transport Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sendmail.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2015-08-23 10:57:25 EDT; 12min ago

Aug 23 10:57:25 test systemd[1]: Starting Sendmail Mail Transport Agent...
Aug 23 10:57:25 test systemd[1]: sendmail.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
Aug 23 10:57:25 test systemd[1]: Failed to start Sendmail Mail Transport Agent.
Aug 23 10:57:25 test systemd[1]: Unit sendmail.service entered failed state.
```

Comment: `sendmail` typically logs, finding those logs might be handy (e.g. find where the system `mail` facility syslog messages go); also, you could try starting `sendmail` directly, possibly under `strace`, to see what is going on without `systemd` getting in the way.

Comment: ....not just "handy" - ALWAYS the first place to look when a server fails.

Answer (score 0):

Is following package installed :

```
dove cot & M4
```

Have you redirected changes which you made in "sendmail.mc"

```
#m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
```